# Load Multiple Modules (.psm1) using a single psd1 file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to  organize functions into **multiple .psm1 files** and have them loaded by a **single Module Manifest file (.psd1)** -- such that **Only** the **.psd1 file** would need to have the **same name as the module**.

I think it should be possible. Can anyone help me out please ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Launch the Powershell ISE
2. Use the `New-ModuleManifest` command
3. Follow the instructions here - [How to Write a Module Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When asked for nested modules, key in the module as `Modulepath\Modulename.psm1`
4. Finally, once the .psd1 file is created, load / import it using `Import-Module <<module-name>>`

Comment: Note that the paths in `NestedModules` paths can be relative paths. From my testing, these are relative the the `psd1` file.

Answer (score 6):

You can load them manually in your main module psm1 file using Import-Module calls or by specifying them in the NestedModules key in the manifest file (psd1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you mind providing a small sample for the Nested Module part please ?

Comment: Also, manually putting Import Module calls in a single .psm1 file would be a little error prone because --- what if two same child modules are repeated inside different .psm1 file and I do a remove-module on one of the main .psm1 which contains the child module ? It will remove the child module which the other main .psm1 is also referring to. I know it is a little bit hypothetical, but still a valid one.

Comment: You need to put the modules folders inside your main module directory and add their relative path in the NestedModules key: NestedModules = @('Module1\Module1.psm1','Module2\Module2.psm1')

Comment: Syntax NestedModules = @('Module1\Module1.psm1','Module2\Module2.psm1')  does not work. I used the ISE & used the New-ModuleManifest command. There I keyed in the module names it generated like this -                                        # Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in ModuleToProcess
NestedModules = 'Mod1\Mod1.psm1', 
               'Mod2\Mod2.psm1'

Comment: The Mod1 and Mod2 directories reside in the root directory of the primary module?

Comment: Yes, they do reside in the root directory of the psd1 file something like this - RootModule directory contains - RootModule.psd1, Mod1, Mod2...etc and the Mod1, Mod1 directories in turn have the respective psm1 files.